# Change layout according to wordpress page template NuxtJs

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I want to get change layout according to wordpress page template (i get data with rest api)

**API Data**

```
{
  "id": 47, 
  "template": "test.php",    // need vue template according this 
}
```

```
export default { 
  validate ({ params }) {
    return !isNaN(+params.id)
  },
  async asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    return fetch('http://wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/'+params.postType+'/'+params.id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
          return { users: res } 
      })
  },
  layout () { 
    return 'blog' // Change here according to wordpress page template 
  },
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return fetch('http://wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/'+params.postType+'/'+params.id)` should it be `return fetch('http://wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/'+params.template+'/'+params.id)`?

Comment: How i pass this into layout?

Comment: according to docs, layout can be a function: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-layout/, have you tried to use the fetch call in there?

Comment: @jumper85 see my code i try this. But i unable to pass selected layout from api according to page or post in vue layout

Comment: you're right, tested this back at home, it didn't work because layout cannot be async. I created an answer with an alternative way I tested succefully, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to pass something from middleware to store which you can use inside the layout function. Here is the basic example I put together.

`middleware/get-layout.js` I simulate an async call here, could also be result of axios.post() for example

```
export default async (ctx) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // you can also access ctx.params here
        ctx.store.commit('setLayout', 'new');
        resolve();
    });
}
```

`store/index.js` nothing crazy here

```
export const state = () => ({
    layout: ''
})

export const mutations = {
    setLayout(state, layout) {
        state.layout = layout;
    }
}
```

Middleware can either be registered globally for every route in `nuxt.config.js` or only for pages where you need this logic.

Finally using it in page component `layout` property:

```
layout(ctx) {
  return ctx.store.state.layout;
}
```

I tested it with `new.vue` inside `layout` folder.